# References for Littelmann Path models and related combinatorial objects

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

I am looking for a reference (preferably textbook or lecture notes) having Littelmann path models and it's uses in representation theory, combinatorics. I am aware of the original papers by Littelmann. So no need to post them. 
I apologize if this question is not for this site.

Comment: As far as I know, such a source does not exist.

Comment: You may be interested in checking the PhD thesis by Reda Chhaibi - not a textbook though. https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0902